# no se que mal puede tener el codigo

Tags: revisión-de-código

hago un custom post type y al momento de hacer que se vea en wordepress sale en blanco la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! El código se comparte como texto (así como te vamos a responder sin imágenes para que no tengas que transcribir). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Saludos Matias, bienvenido a SOes, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 te ayudará a realizar un buen formato de preguntas :D

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto resuelva el problema pero en la variable $labels el ultimo objeto que le agregas tiene una ","
"...´manu_name' => 'Productos',};"
Deberías de quitarla ya que la variable espera que después de manu_name venga otro objeto